# Get a specific column in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, selector

What I want is to get a specific table column using jquery, so far what I have is this, that selects the first column:

```
table.find(tr > td:first-child)
```

But I want to be able to select any column so I can copy it to another table, is there a way to do this for example :

```
td:n-child
```

so I can send it the number of column and get all the data from that specific column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

for instance for selecting the 2nd  element, you would:

```
table.find("tr > td:nth-child(2)");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
table.find("tr > td").eq(n);
```

I just wrote this from the heart, so I can't confirm if it works, but I think this is the syntax to do this.

Answer (score 0):

> **:eq() Selector :** Description: Select the element at index n within the matched set.

You could use **[`:eq() Selector`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)**, e.g :

```
$('tr > td:eq(n)')
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('td:eq(2)').css('background-color','green')

$('tr:eq(2) td:eq(0)').css('background-color','red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>B1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>A2</td>
    <td>B2</td>
  </tr>  
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>A3</td>
    <td>B3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```